# How can I categorize files in a directory based on their content?

Tags: bash, csv, time

I have a directory which contains a lot of CSV files. The CSV files have many columns the first of which is a timestamp (as number of seconds since the UNIX Epoch). I want to categorize files in the directory based on the value of that timestamp column in the first line of each file. (There is no header row in the files).

I want a bash script that run on the directory every two minutes and categorize files in sub-directories in the following layout:

```
YYYY/
  └── MM/
       └── DD/
```

Is it possible? How can I do that?

Content of CSV file is like below:

```
timestamp,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I
```

for example:

```
1565592149,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash -
for f in *.csv; do
  IFS=, read -r timestamp rest < "$f" &&
    printf -v dir '%(%Y/%m/%d)T' "$timestamp" &&  
    mkdir -p -- "$dir" &&
    mv -- "$f" "$dir/"
done
```

Example:

```
$ head -- *.csv
==> test2.csv <==
1328012580,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I

==> test.csv <==
1565592149,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I
$ that-script
$ tree
.
├── 2012
│   └── 01
│       └── 31
│           └── test2.csv
└── 2019
    └── 08
        └── 12
            └── test.csv

6 directories, 2 files
```

Comment: Nice! (Requires Bash 4.2 or later.)

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish the 'every 2 minutes' part of you question, you can put a script like the one Stephane Chazelas made, and invoke it using a cron job.

For example, if your CSV files were at `/home/user/data` and in that folder you have the script in `script.sh`

- you could then run `crontab -e` to edit a the users crontab
- At the end of the file you would add `*/2 * * * * cd /home/user/data && /home/user/data/script.sh`

This would cause the script to be run every 2 minutes, if you wanted to change the frequency you would just change the parts with the `*`, you can use [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#*/2_*_*_*_*) if you are unfamiliar with crontab setup.